# What is the difference in the meaning between "busy in studying" and "busy studying"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in the meaning between two sentences,

> 1) He was busy **in** studying.
>
> 2) He was busy studying.

Does "1) He was busy in studying" mean "He was busy when he was studying"(for example, When he was studying, his mother called him and his friends called him etc.) ?

Does "2)He was busy studying" mean "He was studying very hard" ?

Comment: The difference is that the second sounds idiomatic. The first would be fine if you substituted *at* for *in*: *He was busy at studying*.

Comment: Do you have an example using "busy in studying" in a sentence?  "Busy *with* studying" seems possible, but I can't recall hearing "busy *in*".

Comment: In south korea. "be busy in ~ing" phrase is often used. source:: http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=kr&isOnlyViewEE=N&query=busy%20in%20studying

Comment: In south korea. We did not distinguish between "in ~ing" and "~ing" so that we very often have been learned that "He was busy in studying" is " "He was busy studying". Many of us have thought that "in" is omitted. https://kin.naver.com/search/list.nhn?query=busy+in+%7Eing

Comment: example of "be busy in ~ing" phrase : http://endic.naver.com/search_example.nhn?sLn=kr&examType=example&query=busy+in+studying&pageNo=2

Comment: If we searched at naver english-korean dictionary, we have meeted like that "busy in ~ing" sentence" ===> [일반]I was busy in packing up to go home. 
[일반] I am very busy in doing my homework. 
[일반] He is very busy in canvassing for the election

Comment: That is a mistake in that dictionary, It should say:  He was busy packing up to go home. to be busy [doing something].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are meanings that the phrases have. In any other situation, one wouldn't say "busy in studying," it's only to show a state of being: studying.

Though saying "busy in" works, English speakers tend to say "busy studying." This is because using the "in" sounds almost too formal for everyday conversation,  and people do not bother using sentences in that way.

If you do not know which is most appropriate, just stick with "busy studying" and it will sound good no matter the context.

Comment: Can you provide a good example of: to be busy IN [verb: ing??]